# What VB.Net Frameworks Do You Recommend?

Tags: vb.net, templates, frameworks

I have been looking at the PDSA.Net Productivity Framework. Has anyone else worked with it? What was your opinion? Do you know of any other similiar products?

Comment: Let me mention that if x framework is packaged as a DLL and is meant for C# you may also use it in VB.Net unless it uses language-specific features.

Comment: I'd also suggest that if one is looking to enhance one's productivity, one should strongly consider not coding VB.NET anymore.  LINQ and lambdas in VB.NET are positively painful IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't touch that thing for all the tea in China.

Anyone who markets their product as they do, as a "complete productivity solution" with "no competition" is being disingenuous at best.  They smell very fly-by-night to me, and without a concrete "smoking gun" feature that will save you a demonstrable amount of time over MVC/EF/MSTest, I'd avoid them.

What do you need?  An O/R mapper?  NHibernate is free and Entity Framework 4.0 is quite good (though the previous version was lacking).  Do you need a web framework?  ASP.NET MVC 3 is about to be released, with some major new features and benefits.

Comment: Havent't heard of myself, but seem to be on the market since 1991: http://www.pdsa.com/Customers/Default.aspx

Comment: PDSA themselves have a fine reputation. The namesake of the company is a well respected author. That said, I was just curious if anyone else had used this toolset before or if there was anything else like it.

Comment: As for what I need (just noticed you asked that)... I'm just looking for productivity tools to reduce redundant coding.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's just not specific enough.  Where are you finding that you have repetitive coding?  With your data model?  With your web templates?  With your stylesheets?